# Extract Day from Timestamp in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to analyze the logs using PIG. There is a need to extract the Day from the timestamp. Below is the sample log.
Sample Log-

```
122.172.200.100 - - [17/Oct/2014:00:04:36 -0400] "GET /tag/hbase-sink/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15997 "https://www.google.co.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
```

I have loaded the log files using below command

```
logs = LOAD 'sample_log' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.apachelog.CombinedLogLoader() AS (addr: chararray, logname: chararray, user: chararray, time: chararray,method: chararray, uri: chararray, proto: chararray,status: int, bytes: int, referer: chararray, userAgent: chararray);
```

Now I extracted the Date from the time using DateExtractor as below

```
foreach_logs = FOREACH logs GENERATE org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.util.apachelogparser.DateExtractor(time));
```

Now I have to extract the Day from the date. I have tried using GetDay but it is not working. Can anyone know how to extract the Day from the Date?

Answer (score 1):

First ensure you are getting the field loaded correctly into the variable `time`.Then convert the `time` to a datetime object using `ToDate(time,'yyyy/MM/dd:HH:mm:ss')` and then use `GetDay()`.Assuming you have correctly loaded the data.

```
foreach_logs = FOREACH logs GENERATE GetDay(ToDate(time,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z'));
```

Comment: Yes, i can see the time variable has value '26/Apr/2000:00:23:48 -0400'. Now If I do like foreach_logs = FOREACH logs GENERATE GetDay(ToDate(time,'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')); then I am getting Error like 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "26/Apr/2000:00:23:48 -0400" is malformed at " -0400"'. Not Sure what to provide for -400 in To_Date function.

Comment: I can extract the Day after taking substring.

foreach_logs = FOREACH logs GENERATE GetDay(ToDate(SUBSTRING(time,0,(int)SIZE(time)-6),'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss'));

Comment: @arunkindra No need for substring.You should be able to use 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z' as the format

Comment: No, it is not working. 

I received the below error.
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias foreach_logs. Backend error : Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS)[datetime] - scope-64 Operator Key: scope-64) children: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "26/Apr/2000:00:23:48 -0400" is malformed at " -0400"